# Flashing original BIOS onto Thinkpad Yoga 14

Tags: boot, bios, thinkpad

My work laptop is a Thinkpad P50 and my personal laptop is a Thinkpad Yoga 14.  To get linux onto my P50 without loosing VPN (which isn't supported on Linux at my work), I used CloneZilla to clone the P50 to the Yoga 14.

It worked great for several months.  Then I stupidly pushed the Lenovo update app on the Yoga which wanted to do a BIOS upgrade and I stupidly agreed.

Now it won't boot at all.  I hear a single beep and get a black screen.  I disconnected the CMOS battery and flushed any remaining current, still the same issue.

This [link](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/solutions/migr-46018) says it might be an LCD issue, but I am very certain it's a BIOS issue so I am not ready to do what's on that list just yet.

After a quick search, I wasn't able to find a good tutorial on flashing a BIOS with a black screen.

I am not great at hardware, but as DIY projects, I use micro controllers like STM32's, and SOC's like raspberry pi's.  So I am not averse to hardware work.

Does anyone how I can flash a BIOS onto a seemingly "bricked" laptop?

**EDIT**

There are signs of life now! On boot, the lights under the keyboard go on for a few seconds, and the `Fn` light stays on.  I can hear/feel some humming and spinning.

I firstly disconnected the HD and added a monitor over HDMI, but same results.  Plugged the HD back in now.

Looks it's not a BIOS problem, but some hardware problem.  I reseated the RAM yet still no luck.

This is most likely an LCD issue.  So how can I trouble shoot that further?

Also, without the DC adapter (i.e. on battery) the laptop goes dead.

Comment: Remove request for a tutorial as this is off-topic.

Comment: Flash update tools should check the hardware - flashing a wrong BIOS with vendor tools is highly unusual. You could just have another hardware problem that manifested at this time (or prevented the flash update from running smoothly).

Comment: This is likely a BIOS setting... Try enabling "Legacy Boot" or disabling "Secure Boot" or similar options. Rapidly tap F1 while booting to access the BIOS setup.

Comment: @acejavelin looks you didn't read carefully! I am getting a black screen, so how can I see the BIOS settings?

Comment: Like I said... Tap F1 repeatedly as soon as you hit the power, the default state is not to pause or show the logo or BIOS screen, just go to Windows 10 immediately via EFI boot. If that fails you will likely need to contact Lenovo for repair.